# Scroll smoothly to a specific div on a different page using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a main menu which is displaying on every page of the site. One link in that menu is linked to a specific div on the home page.

I want when I click on that link it should scroll to 50 pixels above that div.

So when I am on the home page then when I click on it, it should scroll smoothly to 50 pixels above that specific div.

And when I am on a different page and click on that link it should redirected to home page and scroll to 50 pixels above that specific div.

Code I have tried

```
    <a href='/#element_id'>Link</a>
$('a').click(function() {
        var divLoc = $('#element_id').offset();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: divLoc.top-50}, "slow");
      });
```

but this only work when I am on the home page as that specific div is on home page.

Any I idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you share your code from what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this before on my company website, check www.CreaDevSolutions.com, then chose a service from the services menu, it will take you there and will scroll smoothly using jquery animate to the service description.

the idea is very simple:

1- you need a communication way between both pages via serverside code or via Url 
parameters,or cookies, i used Url Parameters, and what i pass is the element Id.

2- when the page loads check if there are any variables in the url param are pointing somewhere (check the line 552 getUrlVars()).

3- if there is a value retrieved then i call function animateToElement() which is on line 557

Comment: Dear god man limit yourself to have half a second animations, fadeouts, scrollTos etc in jQuery for a while. You services scroll gives me enough time to read all the other services before the scroll is complete. When in doubt 500 is a good time animation jQuery value. Check out http://www.homevana.com/ for a more user friendly scroll speed.

Comment: @BrianOgden i am aware that its not complete yet, i didn't have time to go back and tinker about it.and i beg to differ, i think it depends on where and what the scrolling is used for determines the speed of the animation, and there is the matter of taste in it isn't it?.

Comment: Yes and I noticed the animation increases in speed the longer you scroll which is good but I would still speed it up overall as, preference or not the normal user is one your website for seconds before never coming back so they are fickle and want the information quickly without any kind of perceivable delay, so in that sense it really isn't preference.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your link a url of the format `http://mysite.com/homepage/#the-div-class-i-want-to-scroll-to`

Then add this js code to your homepage head section

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      /*if you use the id of the div no need for the replace*/
      var target = $(document.location.hash.replace("#","."));
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top-50
            }, 1000);/*animate in 1sec, you may change this as you like*/
          }
});
```

I just noticed that this is what you have tried, so make sure you place the js code at the correct place of your homepage, i.e. load js in head within document ready.

Comment: target.length returns 0 therefore if statement not executed.

Comment: @Ahmad it is because you are using an id, so there is no need to use replace please remove it i.e. `var target = $(document.location.hash);`  .  This is a generic approach that will work regardless of the id you use in your div, otherwise you may just hardcode the id (which is not good), as you have tried in your code i.e. `var target = $('#element_id');`

Comment: I am not using the replace. I am just using target = $(document.location.hash);

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an element id match, just use a name value for the anchor tag to scroll too:

```
  $('.scroll-anchor').click(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top
            }, 500);
            return false;
        });

<a class="scroll-anchor" href="#myreusableanchorname">My Resuable scroll for each page</a>

 <a name="myreusableanchorname"></a>
```

Comment: yes the first <a> is the clickable link that a user can interact with,  the second is the position markerthat the user will be scrolled to on the web page